# Linking VS2005 static library with gcc in Windows

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-studio-2005

Is it possible to link a static library built with VS2005 into an application that is to be built with gcc (in Cygwin)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike UNIX where there was no standard C++ ABI for years, Windows has had a standard C++ ABI from the beginning.  So, yes, [it's possible](http://oldwiki.mingw.org/index.php/sample%20DLL).  But it [can be difficult](http://oldwiki.mingw.org/index.php/CreateImportLibraries).

Comment: I never got it working, I tried creating a DLL instead and that worked like a charm.

Comment: I'm sorry the static option didn't work.  I've noticed Windows sometimes has trouble if I name my output files "file.o" instead of "file.obj".  I haven't yet figured out why that is.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically it should work, but I would suggest to just try it.

Answer (score 0):

I used to link a *.dll in G++ which compiled with a *.lib, It works well currently, but I'm not sure about static library, May be you can compiled it in dll for a try. 
Good luck.